# OpenStack on docker

Tags: openstack

I am looking for a docker image of openstack in docker hub for creating a private cloud. My purpose is to offer computing services. Can someone suggest me some image of docker hub? I want a image with "some kind of documentation". The current images I have been finding only have a one sentence of documentation

Comment: check this out, https://redhatstackblog.redhat.com/2015/07/16/containerize-openstack-with-docker/

Answer (score 0):

Look at Kolla-Ansible. Kolla-Ansible is a set of Ansible modules that can create a containerized deployment of OpenStack, with the services running on individual containers